# How the following simplification is made?

Tags: calculus, summation, convex-optimization, constraints

I am trying to understand how eq. (1) is simplified to eq. (2), but not getting it clearly.

$ U_P(X,P) = \sum_{j}p_{cj}+\sum_i \sum_j x_{ij}p_{ij} -\psi \sum_i \sum_j \sum_{m \in \mathcal{B}} x_{ij}p_{ij}|g_{jm}|^2$  ---(1)

$ U_P(X,P) = p_{cj}+ (1 -\sum_{m \in \mathcal{B}} \psi x_{ij}|g_{jm}|^2) p_{ij} $  ---(2)

Also, there is a constraint that $ \sum_j x_{ij} =1 $.

I am not getting how the summation in eq. (1) got disappeared in eq. (2).

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Where is this problem from? Might be a typo, since $j$ has no meaning outside of the summation.

Comment: Thank you sir for your response.... Its from one of the research paper... I also think that its a typo...